# Submitting code from my R package to a conference

Tags: journals, paper-submission, code

I'm submitting a paper to a conference. The conference encourages also submitting code for reproducibility. My paper builds upon a previous paper, which had a corresponding R package. Therefore, for this paper I've been updating this R package with the various modifications that the new paper presents (but I haven't made these changes public). When submitting my code, should I say something like 'This code has been adapted from the XXX package'? Or could this be seen as breaching anonymity - even though I don't state it's my package?

Comment: The answer depends on the conference. Conferences often have more detailed instructions than "anonymous", did you check what they say? If they are not clear enough, ask the chair, it is their job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The version reviewed and the version published don't need to be identical in most cases. For the reviewed version say "adapted from XXX with permission". Take advice from the program/committee chair about changing those last two words.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't include such a statement, then you're not adequately showing the provenance of your code, just as surely as if you left out important citations.  In addition to the obvious academic concerns this would cause, it could certainly cause licensing issues down the line.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think "This code has been adapted from the XXX package" breaks anonymity, but you should probably mention this issue to the conference people when you submit the paper.

Also you should check the license conditions for the package. Pretend you are not the package author and see if other people would be allowed to adapt it like this.